# Should I buy the memento plates?

Tags: solatorobo-red-the-hunter

In the China Shop in Airedale, you can buy plates that are mementos of your journey. They cost $300 each, and there are quite a few of them.

Other than to haves nice random record of my journey, is there a good reason to buy the plates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Et vous voilà!* If you want to see the cutscenes again, then yes. Other than that they serve no purpose.

I sunk all my hard earned Rings on fishing and (rare) parts.